How do I specify the scene for a webview?
Ive been trying to get WebView working on my javafx app, but I dont know how.
This is the controller
package com.adventureg147.mclauncher;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebHistory;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private WebView webView;
    private WebEngine engine;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        engine = webView.getEngine();
        loadPage();
    }
    public void loadPage() {
        engine.load("https://www.google.com/");

    }


    @FXML
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;

    public void switchToMP(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MPMenu.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void switchToShop(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ShopMenu.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void switchToNews(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("NewsMenu.fxml"));
            stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
    }

}

The block of code above has two different parts basically;
-One to switch scenes
-The other for the web view
I dont even know if I'm meant to specify a scene or anything, I'm kinda new to this.
Here is the fxml for the scene im trying to add webview to btw
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1250.0" style="-fx-background-color: RoyalBlue;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.adventureg147.mclauncher.Controller">
   <children>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="90.0" stroke="TRANSPARENT" strokeType="INSIDE" width="1250.0" />
      <Button layoutX="87.0" layoutY="1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToMP" prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="250.0" style="-fx-background-color: dodgerblue;" text="MODPACKS">
         <font>
            <Font name="Lato Light" size="32.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="472.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToNews" prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="135.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1177da;" text="NEWS">
         <font>
            <Font name="Lato Light" size="32.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="337.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToShop" prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="135.0" style="-fx-background-color: dodgerblue;" text="SHOP">
         <font>
            <Font name="Lato Light" size="32.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <ImageView fitHeight="87.0" fitWidth="87.0" layoutY="2.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../icon.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" layoutY="89.0" prefHeight="712.0" prefWidth="1250.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>

Main class:
package com.adventureg147.mclauncher;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MCLauncher extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage MenuMain) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginMenu.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        Image icon = new Image("icon.png");
        MenuMain.getIcons().add(icon);
        MenuMain.setResizable(false);

        MenuMain.setTitle("MC Launcher");
        MenuMain.setScene(scene);
        MenuMain.show();
    }

}

I tried to "specify" the scene by copying and pasting one of the "switchToX" things, that didnt work.

I added the main class to the post, also the first block was the controller, there's an other controller used for the "login" but idk if you wanted me to provide that or not

What specifically do you mean by "not working"? What actually happens?

You don't "specify the scene for a webview", at least not directly.
For an FXML-initialized scene graph, the FXMLLoader returns an object graph which is a node tree.  You add that node tree either as the root of a scene (which is what I do in this example) or as a child of a node that is already in a scene.
This code from the application class start method does that:
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(WebViewApp.class.getResource("webview.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();


It is hard to say what your issue is from the code provided.
However, here is some code that works, you can compare it to your implementation to help learn how to debug and fix your implementation.
WebViewApp.java
package org.example.webviewdemo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class WebViewApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(WebViewApp.class.getResource("webview.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

WebViewController.java
package org.example.webviewdemo;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class WebViewController {
    @FXML
    private WebView webView;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}

WebView.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1250.0" style="-fx-background-color: RoyalBlue;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.webviewdemo.WebViewController">
    <children>
        <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="90.0" stroke="TRANSPARENT" strokeType="INSIDE" width="1250.0" />
        <Button layoutX="87.0" layoutY="1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="250.0" style="-fx-background-color: dodgerblue;" text="MODPACKS">
        </Button>
        <Button layoutX="472.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="135.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1177da;" text="NEWS">
        </Button>
        <Button layoutX="337.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="135.0" style="-fx-background-color: dodgerblue;" text="SHOP">
        </Button>
        <ImageView fitHeight="87.0" fitWidth="87.0" layoutY="2.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
        </ImageView>
        <WebView fx:id="webView" layoutY="89.0" prefHeight="712.0" prefWidth="1250.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>

module-info.java
module org.example.webviewdemo {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;

    opens org.example.webviewdemo to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.example.webviewdemo;
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>webview-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>webview-demo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javafx.version>22.0.1</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

